# Why does the VSCode ruby debugger show mutiple active connections on 127.0.0.1 p1234

Tags: ruby, debugging

I am unable to debug Ruby programs in VSCode gives error

```
ECONNREFUSED ::1:1234
```

in debug console which I believe is the same error get when starting a debug session without ending the first.  Typically a reboot/restart resolves the problem.  In my case I have restarted multiple times and powered down once, also have followed several post on web about resetting network - no help.

After power down and before running vscode (nothing else run first) did a `netstat -a` and it showed no activity for `127.0.0.1:1234`.

After running vscode and command then shows an active connection.

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:1234         XPS:0                  LISTENING
```

`netstat -a` still reports the same well after vscode terminated. NOTE `netstat -b` shows no activity on that port.

The last step I took was reinstall vscode and disable all extensions except for Ruby, VSCode rdgb, VSCode ruby. Result was

```
Fatal exception in DebugThread loop: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 1234
```

program in execution was

```rb
puts  "starting"; exit
```

and the `launch.json` was

```json
{
            "name": "MAIN",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.rb"
        },
```

Debugging other programs (untouched and prev no problems) produces same result but runs to completion when not in debug mode.

I had a similar problem about 2 years ago and after several days of trying multiple things the problem simply disappeared without me being able to identify why it was rectified.

Prior to the problem appearing only other thing done remotely related was running `bundler install` while looking at an article documenting using `Gemfile` to control updates.

Comment: Please define "rubby deugger".

Comment: @CarySwoveland are you using VS Code for Ruby?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, no, I wasn't even aware of the IDE. I looked it up and my try using it. Right now I mainly use Jupyter.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I haven't heard of Jupyter, Is it an ide? Can you debug the code? Can you give me the link I can download and use it?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, see [this article](https://medium.com/@leslie.sage/jupyter-notebooks-for-ruby-1e380a584c87) entitled *Jupyter Notebooks for Ruby*.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question i looked in to sysinternals and found  tcpview which shows the following

```
ruby.exe,18668,TCP,Listen,127.0.0.1,1234,0.0.0.0,0,9/16/2023 12:33:37 PM,ruby.exe,,,,
```

I used `tcpview` to kill the process (NOTE THE MAIN VSCODE WINDOW DID NOT TERMINATE)  and reran vscode and it gave me

```
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.3/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:106: warning: undefining the allocator of T_DATA class Debase::Context
```

Not sure what error is but does not relate to this problem.

The program ran to completion in debug mode multiple times so looks like interim solution to problem.

NOTE After killing process with `tcpview` `netstat -a` no longer reports activity on 127.0.1 port 1234

NOTE: Looks like good solution when accidentally run a second debug process without terminating first.  Attempted to prove this by starting new debug session while stopped at a break point multiple times.  At no time did I get the multiple connection error.  Appears to fix the problem.

Comment: Am using extensions Ruby  v0.28.1, VS Code plugin for connecting with the Ruby LSP, Ruby Solargraph v0.24.0, Ruby's rdbg debugger support for VSCode, VSCode Ruby v0.28.0 and ruby gems debug (1.8.0, 1.6.3) and ruby-debug-ide (0.7.3)

Answer (score 0):

Am using extensions Ruby v0.28.1, VS Code plugin for connecting with the Ruby LSP, Ruby Solargraph v0.24.0, Ruby's rdbg debugger support for VSCode, VSCode Ruby v0.28.0 and ruby gems debug (1.8.0, 1.6.3) and ruby-debug-ide.

Got a little further insight into problem, when run debug and is failing the connection is made to 127.0.0.1,1234 but no debug toolbar appears and program is not executed.  The connection is never released.  Next attempt gives the double 127.0.0.1,1234 connection problem. Connection is never released until i do so in tcpview.

NOTE: At same time as problem started occurring i started getting warning messages on each debug run, so I had somehow screwed up my debug environment. Therefore will no longer peruse this issue as have uninstalled both ruby 3.2 and VSCode.  Then installed ruby 3.1 and VSCode.  I do have an issue with my current install launch.json file which i will ask as a new question.

Thanks for your input.  Issue is closed